# "open_basedir restriction" but project is within the allowed paths

Tags: php.ini

I had a project working right, but suddenly I'm getting a *Database connection error*. Looking at the Apache2 logs I can see these lines:

> PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(STYLESHEETPATH/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (...) in /webDir/project/wp-includes/template.php on line 467
>
> PHP Warning:  file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(TEMPLATEPATH/index.php) is not within the allowed path(s): (...) in /webDir/project/wp-includes/template.php on line 470

But in `php.ini` the project IS within the allowed paths:

open_basedir = /webDir/project:/usr/share/phpmyadmin

So what could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Strange behavior, but solved just restarting the `mysql` service:

```
service mysql restart
```